# flutter json_serializable generated code analysis error error: Missing parameter type for 'e'

Tags: json, flutter, serialization

As the title states, the generated code shows an error for 'e'. The error states *error: Missing parameter type for 'e'.* Of course, if it was okay to modify the generated code, I could do that. However, that seems a very bad precedent.

The generated code is:

```
RatingResponseModel(
      propertyId: json['propertyId'] as String,
      ownerId: json['ownerId'] as String,
      renterId: json['renterId'] as String,
      ratedDate: DateTime.parse(json['ratedDate'] as String),
      ratings: (json['ratings'] as List<dynamic>)
          .map((e) => RatedDimensionModel.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>))
          .toList(),
    );
```

The class looks like:

````
part 'rating_response_model.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class RatingResponseModel {
  RatingResponseModel({
    required this.propertyId,
    required this.ownerId,
    required this.renterId,
    required this.ratedDate,
    required this.ratings,
  });

  /// A necessary factory constructor for creating a new User instance
  /// from a map. Pass the map to the generated `_$MyClassNameFromJson()`
  /// constructor. The constructor is named after the source class.
  factory RatingResponseModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$RatingResponseModelFromJson(json);

  /// `toJson` is the convention for a class to declare support for
  /// serialization to JSON. The implementation simply calls the private,
  /// generated helper method `_$MyClassNameToJson`.
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$RatingResponseModelToJson(this);

  final String propertyId;
  final String ownerId;
  final String renterId;
  final DateTime ratedDate;
  final List<RatedDimensionModel> ratings;
}```

The app seems to work properly, as do the unit tests - including the to/from json unit tests. Showing a syntax error in generated code is annoying. It makes me wonder if I have done something wrong. Worse, will it fail unexpectedly?

I am using json serializable: ^6.1.4 and json annotation: ^4.4.0. Flutter is 2.8.1. The ide is Intellij IDEA 2021.3.1.
````

Comment: It's ok to modify, I also did in my cases were some keys were generating the same name due to conflict issues, but it worked for me. As long as you are changing naming it's okay, logic should be untouched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed:

```
.map((e) =>
```

To:

```
.map((dynamic e) =>
```

And, as @hiashutoshsingh stated, this solved the problem with the analysis error. The drawback to this solution is that everytime you run build runner you will need to change the generated code again.